# Getting HTTP status code from a POST request in WSO2 API

Tags: xml, wso2, http-status-codes, wso2-esb

I've been writing an API for a project I'm working on and I've written a resource that takes a POST request, containing the `type` of the request and the `url` of the API, for example:

```
{ 
    "test":{ 
        "type":"DSS", 
        "url":"http://localhost:8280/testsuite/general/test"
    }
}
```

In the response, I just need the HTTP status code (`200` for okay, `404` for not found, etc., etc.) but every method of getting this that I have tried has only seen it return null for the code.

I saw one post on here that posed a couple of suggestions which I've included below; neither of these worked.

`<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="status" expression="get-property('HTTP_SC')"/>`
`<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="status" expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')"/>`
`<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="status" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"/>`

For all of the above attempts, it just returns null for the value of `status`.

[Linked is a kobra.io page with the resource I've written on it.](https://kobra.io/#/e/-K4NMZbmh3zTJVvF4jWv)  If anyone can offer some guidance on how to get the response code out, that'd be hugely appreciated as it's been a thorn in my side for a couple of days now..

For reference, I'm using WSO2 v4.9.

Comment: try <property name="httpStatusCode" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.  I spoke with my immediate superior and he said to just hardcode the values as if it's returning anything that isn't a failure, it'll have a 200 code due to the setup of the platform we're working from so, while not an ideal solution, that's what we had to go with.

Comment: have you tried to log the status code ? if it's correctly coming from the service you are calling? like this  <log level="custom">
                <property name="provider status code " expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')"/>
            </log> , you can enable wire logs to see if the status is coming correctly